# how to remove: _checker_version 1" in androidstudio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, atomic

Be me.  Be programming n00b.

Downloaded AtomicKotlin course plugin for Android Studio 4.2.1

Unable to correctly submit exercises, even when copy pasting the solution code.

"_checker_version 1"  is printed as the first line in all my exercises.  See picture.

Appreciate the help!

[Bottom right of this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze3XC.png)

Answer (score 2):

Select Project View

Go to file `build.gradle (AtomicKotlinCourse)`

look for `def printOutput(def output)` method

Replace

```
def printOutput(def output) {
    return tasks.create("printOutput") {
        println "#educational_plugin_checker_version 1"
        def lines = output.toString().split("(?<=\n)|(?=\n)")
        for (line in lines) {
            println "#educational_plugin" + line
        }
    }
}
```

With

```
def printOutput(def output) {
    return tasks.create("printOutput") {
        def lines = output.toString().split("(?<=\n)")
        for (line in lines) {
            println "#educational_plugin" + line
        }
    }
}
```

Tested for a few exercises working fine.